# c# OO advice for inherited attribute classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I would like to get some OO correct advice please.
What is the correct way of accessing attribute data from inherited classes.

Assuming 3 classes:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
  public int Id {get; set; }    
  public int Wheels {get; set; }
  public string Name {get; set; }
  public string Color {get; set; }
 }
 public class Car : Vehicle
 {
 }
 public class Truck : Vehicle
 {
  public int LoadCapacity {get; set; }  
 }
```

My first thought was to create a repository of some kind that gives me the attributes of whatever I'm looking for.

There are 2 types of queries as I see it that I will need:

1. Return attributes of vehicle with a specific ID
2. Give me all vehiclesof a specific type

So:

```
public class VehicleRepository
{
    ICollection <???> _vehicles;

    ??? GetVehicle(int Id);
    ??? GetVehicles(??? vehicleType);
}
```

The ??? are my unknowns.

My thought was to add something like an interface for IVehicle and implement Vehicle with it.
The result would be something like:

```
public class VehicleRepository
{
    ICollection <IVehicle> _vehicles;

    IVehicle GetVehicle(int Id);
    ICollection <IVehicle> GetVehicles(IVehicle vehicleType);
}
```

This obviously doesnt work.

```
public IVehicle GetVehicle(int Id)
{
    return _vehicles.First(x=>x.Id == Id);
    // The above want compile as the interface has no attributes
}
```

If I use Vehicle instead of IVehicle, the 'First(x=>x.Id == Id)' will work fine but it will not return 'LoadCapacity' if the vehicle is a truck.

Looking at the GetVehicles function, I was thinking something like:

```
public ICollection <T> GetVehicles <T> ()
{
    var vehicles = _vehicles.Where(???);
    return vehicles;
}
```

A bit lost on what should go in there BUT I would like to avoid reflection and just reading assemblies and class types, etc.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: By "attribute" do you mean "property"?  Attributes are things like `[Obsolete]` or `[Serializable]`.

Comment: Sorry I did mean properties, in this case: Id, Wheels, Name, Color, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store and get vericles, all you would need to do is something like:

```
class VehicleRepository {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}
```

to retrieve them, simply use `IEnumerable<T>.OfType<U>()`:

```
VehicleRepository repository = ...
repository.vehicles.OfType<Car>(); // This will get you all of the cars
repository.vehicles.OfType<Truck>(); // This will get you all of the trucks
```

If you wanted to get fancy though, you could make the `VehicleRepository` a collection all its own by making it implement `IEnumerable<T>`. Consider:

```
class VehicleRepository : IEnumerable<Vehicle> {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public IEnumerator<Vehicle> GetEnumerator() {
        return vehicles.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you can query against the collection itself, as in:

```
public static void Main() {
    VehicleRepository repository = ...;

    // Notice that we skip accessing the vehicles member
    // because by implementing IEnumerable<T> this class
    // becomes a collection. Now you can use OfType<T> directly.
    repository.OfType<Car>(); 
}
```

EDIT: To do something like `GetVehicleByID`, you might try something like this:

```
class VehicleRepository : IEnumerable<Vehicle> {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public Vehicle GetVehicleByID(Int32 id) {
        return vehicles[id];
    }
}
```

you could also use an indexer, like so:

```
class VehicleRepository : IEnumerable<Vehicle> {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public Vehicle this[Int32 id] {
        get { return vehicles[id]; }
    }
}
```

To get `LoadCapacity` from a truck, all you would have to do is something like this:

```
public static void Main() {
   VehicleRepository repository = ...

   // Assuming index zero is a truck
   Truck truck = (Truck)repository.GetVehicleByID(0);
   truck.LoadCapacity = ...
}
```

One cheaty way to get all items of a particular type (when bound to the UI, i.e. assuming you're using `Strings`) without using reflection is to match the `ToString` values of the Type names. For example:

```
public static void Main() {
   VehicleRepository repository = ...

   // Assume we're storing off the typename in the UI dropdown.
   // so that when the user selects it, we automatically have the correct
   // type name we want to filter by.
   String truckTypeName = typeof(Truck).GetType().ToString();      

   // Filter only by those types with a matching type name. Inefficient,
   // but it does avoid reflection.
   repository.Where(vehicle => vehicle.GetType().ToString() == truckTypeName)
}
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is there a way of accessing the Vehicle type by type name in runtime. I'm thinking of a dropdown box with all the vehicle types and a selection fires off the method. Also do you have an idea for the GetVehicle(Id) method, it will return a vehicle not an instance of the concrete class. How do I get the class values if I am doing this selection in run time?

Comment: Posted some updated techniques you might use. The UI one is a bit difficult without knowing more specifics, but I did post *a* solution (albeit pretty so-so).

Comment: The Getby ID works fine, thanks. The UI one is pretty much the way I was thinking about but was hoping to avoid the GetType().TosTring(). It's a pretty old approach but I guess if it works, I'll stick to it.

Comment: There are definitely better ways, that's just a one size fits all approach. However, you may consider opening another question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OfType` method to get the items in a collection of a specific type:

```
public ICollection<T> GetVehicles<T>() {
  return _vehicles.OfType<T>();
}
```